# RStudio no muestro import dataset por URL

Tags: r, rstudio

Acabo de empezar con un curso de R y estoy en la parte de importar datos, en el curso sale la opcion de importar desde una URL-

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en mi Rstudio no sale, esto se debe a que me falta algun package? la version que instale (ultima) ya no permite ese tipo de importe?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo hacerlo por comando solo que no me sale la opcion desde el import:

```
> sample <- read.table("http://aprender.uib.es/Rdir/pearson.txt", header=TRUE, quote="\"")
> View(sample)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si mal no recuerdo esta opción fue reemplazada hace tiempo por `"From text (readr)..."`, en la cual puedes indicar la url a importar, haces click en el botón "update" para leer la misma y luego es solo configurar las opciones adecuadas, esto además te genera el código para copiar en el script si lo necesitarás.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabia esa informacion, ya lo realice como me comentas y funciona correctamente solo me pidio instalar un package de curl install.packages("curl") -> http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/curl_3.2.zip